# Site is not displayed correctly on smart phone size screen

Tags: html, mobile, resolution, responsive

Used foundation for the first time as i thought it was an easy way to make a responsive site for all resolutions.

Not responsive at all. I would not say i am knowledgeable regarding web design but i understand how things work.

The site works down to an ipad and looks great however on the smart phone it falls to pieces, background image does not fill screen and nav menu is split onto two lines.

Any advice?

Comment: Could you provide some details, screenshots or source code etc?

Comment: </head>
  <body>
   <nav>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="large-12 medium-12 columns" align="center">
             <ul>
               <li><a href="index.html" title="homepage" target="_self">CREATIVE TRAVELLERS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="careers.html" title="careers" target="_self">CAREERS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutus.html" title="aboutus" target="_self">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus.html" title="contactus" target="_self">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

Comment: meta.foundation-version {
  font-family: "/5.3.3/"; }
meta.foundation-mq-small {
  font-family: "/only screen/";
  width: 0em; }
meta.foundation-mq-medium {
  font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:40.063em)/";
  width: 40.063em; }
meta.foundation-mq-large {
  font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:64.063em)/";
  width: 64.063em; }
meta.foundation-mq-xlarge {
  font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:90.063em)/";
  width: 90.063em; }
meta.foundation-mq-xxlarge {
  font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:120.063em)/";
  width: 120.063em; }